# Google Calendar API - Source Title & Gadget are not working on google calendar event prompt

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-calendar-api

I'm using Javascript version of Google Calendar API to create Events from Ruby on Rails app to User's Google Calendar.

I needed to add custom link and title on Event Prompt (on Google Calendar) from js insert event script. Everything is working fine but `Source` & `Gadget` options are not working as expected.

In `Source`, I have provided URL and Title. Url is there but not the title. In the same way, `Gadget` option is making no difference on Google Event.

```
"gadget": {
    "type": 'object',
    "title": 'Go To Website',
    "link": 'https://url',
    "iconLink": 'https://icon-url',
    "width": 100,
    "height": 100,
    "display": 'chip'
 },
 "source": {
     "url": 'https://url',
     "title": 'Title'
}
```

As per documentation https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events,
There should be a new icon for `Gadget` along with Event Title,
and there should Title with URL for `Source` in Event Prompt.